# $Ax=y$ has a solution for every $y \in Y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear space, $Y$ be a normed linear space and $A:X \to Y$ be a linear operator. Suppose $y_0 \in R(A)$ and $r>0$ are such that the equation $Ax=y$ has solution for every $y\in B_Y(y_0,r)$. Show that $Ax=y$ has a solution for every $y \in Y$.

Need some hints to proceed with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it should be easy to prove the statement if $y_0=0$, because $$y=2r\|y\| \cdot \frac{1}{2r\|y\|}y$$

which means that if $Ax' = \frac{1}{2r\|y\|}y$, then setting $x=2r\|y\| x'$ means that $$Ax=A(2r\|y\| x')=2r\|y\| Ax' = 2r\|y\| \cdot \frac{1}{2r\|y\|}y = y$$

---

So, all you need is to prove that for every $y\in B(0,r)$, the equation $Ax=y$ has a solution.

Take $y\in B(0,r)$ and define $y_b=y_0 + y$. Then clearly $y_b\in B(y_0, r)$, so there exists some $x_b$ such that $Ax_b=y_b$. And you also know of some $x_0$ such that $Ax_0=y_0$.

Now you know that $y=y_0-y_b$, and you know that $y_0=Ax_0$ and you know that $y_b=Ax_b$, and you know that $A$ is linear.

I'll leave it to you to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 2):

Try to "translate" the ball $B_Y(y_0, r)$ to the ball $B_Y(0, r)$: show that for all $y\in B_Y(0, r)$ there is $x\in X$ so that $Ax = y$. Then $A$ is surjective by scaling.

Comment: More general: if $Y$ is a normed space, $U$ is a subspace of $Y$ and if $U$ has an interior point, then $U=Y$. Can you prove this assertion ?

Comment: It seems that your more general question can be proved using the OP's question by setting $X = U, f = i$ the inclusion. @Fred